# Convert if else to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have following  code in c# in which I am searching for lowest price flight .Now I want to convert it to Linq

```
for (; count < _flightSearchController.ListOfContracts.Count; count++)
            {
                contract = (DTContract)_flightSearchController.ListOfContracts[count];
                if (contract.CurrentStatus == AvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE)
                {
                    if (CheckContractCitiesWithSearchCriteria(contract, originAirports, destinationAirports))
                    {
                        //if fare is lower than selected contract.
                        if (lowestPriceContract == null || lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection > contract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection)
                        {
                            lowestPriceContract = contract;
                        }
                        else if (lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection == contract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection)
                        {
                            if (lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceAdult > 0 && (lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceAdult + lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.FareTaxAdult) > (contract.FareDetails.PriceAdult + contract.FareDetails.FareTaxAdult))
                            {
                                lowestPriceContract = contract;
                            }
                            else if (lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceSenior > 0 && (lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceSenior + lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.FareTaxSenior) > (contract.FareDetails.PriceSenior + contract.FareDetails.FareTaxSenior))
                            {
                                lowestPriceContract = contract;
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

}

I tried it to convert but stuck in if else if section.

```
   var q = _flightSearchController.ListOfContracts.ToList<DTContract>()
                    .Where(cont => cont.CurrentStatus == AvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE);
                if (lowestPriceContract == null || lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection > contract.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection)
                {


                }
```

Comment: `if(a) ... else if (b) ... else if (c) ...` will create following cases: `a`, `not a and b`, `not a and not b and c`.. where is a hard part??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Min` extension method:

```
var q = _flightSearchController.ListOfContracts
            .Where(cont => cont.CurrentStatus == AvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE 
                 && CheckContractCitiesWithSearchCriteria(cont, originAirports, destinationAirports))
            .Min(cont=> cont.FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection)
```

**Edit** I had glossed over the tie-breaker part, which makes it a bit more complicated. You can do it with sorting, but this will be slower when there are a lot of contracts:

```
var q = _flightSearchController.ListOfContracts
            .Where(cont => cont.CurrentStatus == AvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE)
                && CheckContractCitiesWithSearchCriteria(cont, originAirports, destinationAirports))
            .OrderBy(cont => FareDetails.PriceForDefaultFlightSelection)
            .ThenBy(cont => cont.FareDetails.PriceAdult + lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.FareTaxAdult)
            .ThenBy(cont => cont.FareDetails.PriceSenior + lowestPriceContract.FareDetails.FareTaxSenior)
            .First();
```

You could implement the `IComparable` interface for the `FareDetails` object to compare the prices, which would allow you to do this:

```
var q = _flightSearchController.ListOfContracts
        .Where(cont => cont.CurrentStatus == AvailabilityStatus.AVAILABLE 
             && CheckContractCitiesWithSearchCriteria(cont, originAirports, destinationAirports))
        .Min(cont=> cont.FareDetails)
```

Comment: if I am not wroing you skip CheckContractCitiesWithSearchCriteria and   else if block